# Can Fedora 28 be installed from an ISO file on an LVM partition?

Tags: installation, fedora, iso-image, lvm

I am attempting a medialess installation of Fedora 28, using an ISO image stored on an LVM partition.

After struggling for a while I found [this post](https://superuser.com/a/1289853/127425) which helped a lot, but I am now encountering the following error :

> dracut-initqueue; /sbin/iso-scan: line 35: rmdir: command not found

From dracut emergency mode I can see this is triggered by

```
rmdir "/run/initramfs/isoscan"
```

(which is created at the beginning of the script).

I guess I could comment this line, however I also found this warning on [F20 documentation](https://docs-old.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/20/html/Installation_Guide/s1-steps-hd-installs-x86.html) :

> You cannot use ISO files on partitions controlled by LVM (Logical Volume Management).

I don't see this warning for more recent Fedora versions, though.  Is it still accurate ?

Comment: FWIW, I ended up using an external disk instead of the LVM partition, and didn't encounter this error.